# How do I get Internet Explorer to handle custom protocol handlers correctly?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, registry

I would like a website I am developing to open `PuTTY` on `ssh://0.0.0.0` type urls. I got this feature working in Chrome and Firefox, but get the following errors in Internet Explorer:

```
Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not have the appropriate permissions to access this item.
```

Followed by:

```
Unable to open this helper application for ssh://0.0.0.0/.

The protocol specified in this address is not valid. Make sure the address is correct, and try again.
```

Here are my registry keys:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ssh]
@="URL:SSH Protocol"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ssh\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ssh\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ssh\shell\open\command]
@="cmd /k set in=\"%l\" & call set in=%%in:ssh:=%% & call set in=%%in:/=%% & call \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\PuTTY\\putty.exe\" %%in%% & exit"
```

I did a quick experiment, and it looks like the issue is due to `cmd` and `call`. As soon as I remove those, I get the expected outcome. However, I still need to do the string manipulation as PuTTY (and an identical situation for `vnc` urls using RealVNC VNC Viewer) only expects the host without the protocol prefix.

Edit: It seems to be `cmd` only that is causing the issue. `call` can be used with the expected behavior.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess there is a permissions issue with `cmd.exe` being called by Internet Explorer. Instead, I had to start entirely over with `PowerShell`. Here is the working registry keys with absolutely no additional scripts or PuTTY program modifications that are shown in some workarounds I found online:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ssh]
@="URL:SSH Protocol"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ssh\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ssh\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ssh\shell\open\command]
@="C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -Command \"$uri = [System.Uri]'%l';&\"${env:ProgramFiles}\\PuTTY\\putty.exe\" -P $uri.Port $uri.GetComponents([System.UriComponents]::UserInfo -bor [System.UriComponents]::Host, [System.UriFormat]::UriEscaped)\""
```

I can now open `SSH` and `VNC` links from all three major browsers.

Comment: Nice but TrimStart doesn't trim a string but all characters in the list passed, meaning that `ssh://shost` will log into `ost`. A solution for that is to use substring: https://gist.github.com/vbfox/a733de9627fe8d26bb80

Comment: @JulienRoncaglia Thanks. I added the change to my answer.

Comment: @ubomb

For some reason with this isn't working for me. instead its just opening an instance of windows explorer.  I'd really like to get it to work if you have any further advice.

p.s. sorry for the necro

Comment: @BrettMoan The only thing I can think of is that my example was a little out of date. It was looking for PuTTY in Window's 32-bit program files. I just changed it to match where PuTTY is now being installed by default. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: For me, clicking on a ssh://x.x.x.x link opens a powershell then quickly switches to a black putty terminal with no connection timeout.